# What is the meaning of single circle breakpoint in visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-mac-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 (Preview) for mac.

This is the usual breakpoint i applied after creating a project.
[normal breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi3vB.png)

But as soon as i build the project the breakpoint changes into a single circle. It does not pause the program. Can anyone tell what it signifies?
[Single circle breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpPpy.png)

Comment: It means that the code in the editor is not the same as the code which has been compiled into the assembly which is currently executing. Just stop debugging and then start it again, that should fix the problem.

Comment: also IIRC if you hover over it, tooltip should appear explaining that

Comment: @tomredfern I have tried that but it's not working for me

Comment: hovering over it also does not show anything @PawełŁukasik

Comment: Then your debug session is picking up an assembly which has different code to that displayed on the screen. Try deleting your build output folders and rebuilding.

Comment: @STembhurkar ok, maybe VS for Mac doesn't do that (strange though)